# Using getElementsByClassName and setAttribute returns undefined error?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction (){
    // some javascript
}
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()");
</script>
<button class="test"> Submit Request </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use JavaScript that executes on page load to add an onclick attribute to my button on the page.

Right now in doing this I get an error that says cannot read proprety 'setAttribute' of undefined.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Note: My only option to access the button is via it's class attribute and I cannot physically modify the button element in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('test')` will return `null` as `DOM` is not ready when you are trying to access the elements.. Write your script before closing `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because the element didn't exist when you were trying to access it. You need to perform the event binding operation `window.onload` event.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
}
```

I would recommend you to use [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and better use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
      document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
});
```

Comment: I know this could be point of argument but why not `DOMContentLoaded` or just writing the script before closing `body` tag ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, Surely `DOMContentLoaded` is better however I don't recommend _writing the script before closing `body` tag_

Comment: @Satpal, Would like to have a justification of _Why you do not recommend that_

Comment: @RayonDabre, Simple because order matter and this leads to error to creep up

Comment: Thank you, this works well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].setAttribute("onclick", myFunction);
```

Notice the quote is removed from myFunction and the parenthesis is also removed as it would not required because you only need to work this function only when the button is clicked.

Comment: I tried this and still get the same error, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you also need to use the code inside window.load or before the closing of the body tag.

Comment: let me try that, I will let you know if window.load works.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, `setAttribute` Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element. Kindly test your solution as I suppose it is not gonna work. It directly adds attributes in the markup much like `<button onclick='myFunction()'>`